# Evaluating the triple integral $\iiint (x-2) \,dx\,dy\,dz$ over a region

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

Here's the question
$$\iiint (x-2) \,dx\,dy\,dz.$$
I am asked to evaluate this integral over the region $$D:=\left \{ (x,y,z) \in\mathbb{R}^3 :1\leq x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq9,x\leq z,z \geq 0\right \}.$$
 I tried to use the spherical coordinates find the solution :

$\begin{cases} z=\rho cos\phi \\ x=sin\phi cos\theta \\ z=sin\phi sin \theta \end{cases}$

I obtained that:

- $ 0 \leq \rho \leq 1 $
- $ 0 \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$
- $ sin \phi * cos \theta\leq cos \phi $

How can i obtain the value of $\theta$ or $\phi$ from the third inequality?
What can I do or what have I done wrong up until now?

Any support for this question would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but "support for this question" (so please don't downvote):  a figure to help visualization.

[image]

It is clear that the OP's inequality on radius is incorrect.  Instead:  $1 \leq \rho \leq 3$